# Python - execute only one value from dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand something. I have code something like this

```
all_commands = {
    'cpu': print('so much cpu'),
    'user': print('so much users')
}

if args[0] in all_show.keys():
    return all_show[args[0]]
```

I want to execute only i.e. second key - 'user' but in every way I know it is executing both of them.
Main goal is to avoid ifology, elif isn't solution. I can't use match case from 3.1 because it should be done in 3.4 version (for compatibility with older Unix systems)
Is there any better solution to do this?
I've searched SO without success.

Comment: Is `all_show` supposed to be `all_commands`?

Comment: Is the code to be executed for a given key (e.g. 'cpu' or 'user') *always* going to be `print(<some string here>)`? Or do you need to execute arbitrary code for a given input?

Comment: no no, there will be code from some functions

Comment: See example of [executing functions mapped to a specific input value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7857880/271415).

Comment: FYI instead of `if x in d.keys()` you can simply write `if x in d`.

Comment: @jarmod thx for feedback I was always calling keys()

Answer (score 5):

You're calling `print()` when you create the dictionary, not when the values are accessed.

You should put functions in the dictionary, then call them when you access it. You can use `lambda` to turn a simple one-liner into a function.

```
all_commands = {
    'cpu': lambda: print('so much cpu'),
    'user': lambda: print('so much users')
}

if args[0] in all_commands:
    return all_commands[args[0]]()
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/DgM0Kt)

Comment: hmm ok, I will do some tests maybe lambdas is the way but now it isn't executing anything, possible there is some simple problem

Comment: I added a link to a demo showing it works. Are you sure you have `()` at the end of the `return` line?

Comment: Your solution works, I have something with inheritance in my classes. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're not storing a function in each key when you create your dictionary, instead you're actually calling `print` on every key.  Instead create functions using `lambda` that you can call later.

```
all_commands = {
    'cpu': lambda: print('so much cpu'),
    'user': lambda: print('so much users')
}
```

Here's how you would call the function for `'cpu'`:

```
all_commands['cpu']()  # prints 'so much cpu'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use lambdas for all_commands:

```py
all_commands = {
    'cpu': lambda: print('so much cpu'),
    'user': lambda: print('so much users')
}

if args[0] in all_commands:
    all_commands[args[0]]()
```